# Bulk Insert with multiple fieldterminator

Tags: sql, sql-server, text

I got a **.txt** file that has a lot of information, I need to save that data per row. Then I'm using a bulk insert in SQL SERVER, so I understand I can use the property **fieldterminator**, if all my data were separated by a single character, but the file I have is separated by different characters, multiple blank spaces, some zeros, plus and minus symbols. I would like to know if there is any way to use several fieldterminator or something similar that allows me to separate strings by multiple characters.

```js
truncate table testtxt


bulk insert testtxt
from 'C:\x\xx\xxx\Desktop\myfolder\myfile.txt'
with(
  DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
  fieldterminator = '                          ',
  rowterminator = '0x0a'
)

select * from testtxt
```

Every row i got in the file look's like this:

> 65505155686   0106201822250981CGO TRANS ELEC                          -000000001876300000001031669100843460CLAUSULA 24 05INX05

At this point i get my info like this:

[image]

If I add more rows, the rows that are between the first and the last are shown as null. In other words, it only separates each row in 2 sections.

Comment: not that i can think of... any way to standardize this before import?

Comment: What are you trying to get (instead of what you are getting now)?  I'm not really following your plain-english description of the problem, so I need an example that is crystal-clear.  I suspect maybe you could do what you want with BCP and a format file.

Comment: I want to separate everything colum1 = 6505155686 ,colum2 = 010620..., column3 = Trans colum4 = Elec colum5 = -0000... etc ...

Comment: Are the fields variable in length, or are they fixed length. Data looking like your sample usually is in a fixed length record, possibly with a ragged right end.

Comment: So why can't you use a blank space as your field terminator?

Comment: @TabAlleman 
Of course I can use the blank space, but not all the file is separated only by blank spaces, some spaces have the length of 3 tabs so it does not help me to contemplate everything by simple blank spaces

Answer (score 1):

Your most flexible solution is to create a SSIS package that uses a script component as a datasource.

You can read the file one row at a time and apply a specific logical definition for each column you want to send to the dataflow.